# How to make a rewrite rule for url folder?

Tags: php

I have a login.php file which is located at my view directory. I want a clean url output that displays http://sample.com/login and not http://sample.com/view/login.php. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you MVC? Any framework used? It looks like a MVC. Then you should always use the Controller to load the view so the link should not contain the `view` folder. So what is your controller php location?

Comment: It's not MVC. Just a basic routing

Comment: What webserver are you using? Different webservers have different ways to configure this.

Comment: I'm using apache. I have a code like this but I think I'm missing something

`RewriteRule ^/login?$ /view/login.php`

Comment: Maybe `RewriteRule ^login view/login.php` works.

Comment: @AkiEru Okay thanks it works now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can add the `.htaccess` file in your view folder and add the below code to your `.htaccess`
2. Then remove the `.php` extension from your links in the code. Like `<a href="login">Login</a>`.

Rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,QSA]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Please let me know, if I misunderstood your requirements, or in case if you need any further assistance.

Comment: ok thanks. Great solution. I placed it in the root directory and it works.

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging.